# C language: Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

For testing, I composed a code to calculate the prime number<50. But I got the Segmentation Fault. And I checked the code by gdb and it shows "primes [index] = p;" is wrong. But I really don't know why and how to fix it, please help me. Many thanks.

OS:Ubuntu 14.04

Kernel:3.19.0-33-generic

Compiler: GCC 4.84

```
    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    int main(void)
    {
     int   p, i, primes[50], index;
     bool isprime;

     primes[0] = 2;
     primes[1] = 3;
     index = 2;

     for (p = 5; p <=50; p+2)
     {
         isprime = true;
         for (i = 0; isprime && ((p/primes[i]) >= primes[i]); i=i+1)
         {
             if (p%primes[i] == 0)
                 isprime = false;
         }

         if  (isprime == true)
         {
             primes [index] = p;
             index = index +1;
         }
     }
     printf ("\n");
     for (i = 0; i <index; i=i+1)
     {
         printf("%i  ", primes[i]);
     }

     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Print `index` and `i` to the screen, does it reach 50? does it go beyond 50?

Comment: Are you sure the code does not index `primes` by any index `>49`? `primes[49]` accesses the 50th element. Indexing C arrays is `0`-based.

Comment: testing in gdb: index = 1128, why?

Comment: "Why?" not check yourself first? Why not single step in the debugger?

Answer (score 7):

You have an inifinite loop because this

```
for (p = 5 ; p <= 50 ; p + 2)
                   //    ^ has no effect
```

you mean

```
for (p = 5 ; p <= 50 ; p += 2)
```

- How did I find this so quickly?

  The fact is I did without reading the code, just copied it and pasted it in my favourite text editor, and then compiled it with `-Wall`, the compiler then told me

  ```
  stack-overflow.c:129:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
       for (p = 5 ; p <=50 ; p + 2)
  ```

Answer (score -3):

in writing `p <=50;`, you will access `primes[50]`, and that index is out of bounds.

primes[49] is the last element.

And you need p+=2 in your loop as your increment, else it will never terminate.

Comment: Not necessarily, `p` is not used as an index there.